# Should I ever use buckshot?

Tags: battlefield-3

In BF3 I always end up using the flechette ammo because it has a much longer effective range.

It apparently has lower damage than buckshot but is always a one hit kill anyway.

Why would I ever use Buck when I can have range and 1HK capability with flechette?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flechette ammo deals around 6 damage less per bullet in close quarters than buckshot. This means that you can be less accurate per shot with buckshot (more bullets can miss) and still do the same or more damage.

Flechette rounds pierce targets better though, so if there are 2-3 targets in a row, you'll get more overall damage per shot, but still less damage on the target in the front.

At maximum damage dropoff, flechette rounds deal about 3-4 more damage per shot.

It all comes down to the fact that because you need less bullets to hit a target in close range with buckshot, you can actually 1 hit kill from further away, as with flechette rounds you need to be close enough to have nearly every bullet hit. Although this is slightly mitigated by the fact that fletchette rounds have a slightly smaller spread, meaning if you're accurate enough, more bullets should hit at range than with buckshot.

Comment: This is probably the better answer.

Comment: Both answers are good but this one has a bit more depth. Marking as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Flechette is probably your best option because it has a smaller spread than buckshot so it is better at a distance. Also, flechette ammo can pierce through structures better.

Buckshot is good for one or two targets, and flechette is better for clusters of enemies.

From another site, someone said:

> Buckshot does 20 damage and drops to 6 at 50m, Flechettes does 14.8->8.4 but goes through players and thin obstacles. Both have 12 shots/flechettes per shell.